# hdaudio hdaudioc0d2: unable to configure , disabling while booting - ubuntu 22.04

Tags: nvidia, 22.04

I'm working with Nvidia 33060 Ti,
after i installed the driver for the GPU I get this message while booting :

"hdaudio hdaudioc0d2: unable to configure , disabling while booting"

I get to the gui login, but every boot I get this message.

Someone know how can what does it mean?